# GroupBy Filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have an array of timeline which I want to divide in groups per date (dd/MM/YYYY). I was trying make my own "groupBy" without any library (which I really prefer), but I got no success. So I decided to search for a library that does it and I found this: [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter), so now I'm trying to use it.

The problem is that I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I followed this [example](http://jsbin.com/zegavo/3/edit?html,js,output) and created my [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sorolizopo/1/edit?html,js,output) to ilustrate my situation. It always says the format date is wrong, why?

By the way, the expected result is:

  Date:
  **17/06/2016**
- Timeline item: an e-mail edited
- Timeline item: an e-mail deleted
- Timeline item: an e-mail edited

  Date:
  **18/06/2016**
- Timeline item: an e-mail added
- Timeline item: an e-mail added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters in Angular are called many times, not just once. So during the first digest, your `created_at` values are converted to `D/M/Y` format. Then, when during the next digest Angular call your filters again, it tries to create a date with already converted value (i.e. `new Date('18/06/2016')`). So you get an *Invalid date* as a result.

The solution is to convert the dates once in the controller before assigning them to the view and omit the `map: ...` filter.

See the [updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xexutuwoki/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thanks for your response, you're right. Dumb mistake. Btw, is there an **easy** way to do it without using angular-filter module?

Comment: Check out [their implementation](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/blob/master/src/_filter/collection/group-by.js) for reference.